# Internet Explorer Debug Mode - Is there a quick way to enable/disable it?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer

I do web site debugging with Internet Explorer (as well as other browsers), but my problem is with Internet Explorer, as it is the browser I usually use for regular browsing.

In order to debug you need to turn on debug mode in the advanced options. OK, fine. It's turned on. But the issue I have, that is quite annoying, is that it seems 30% of websites have JavaScript errors, and Internet Explorer in debug mode causes a popup. This is now also the case with Stack Overflow as well, where I spend a lot of time now. Every time I edit I get a JavaScript error pup up.

I guess it comes down to this: Is there a way to QUICKLY enable and disable debug mode, such as a Hokey, or an add-in, so you don't have to go into Advanced Options to enable and disable?

I should mention I do mainly [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) development and use Visual Studio. I do already use Firefox/[Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) for some scenarios and non Internet Explorer-related issues. I'm not really looking to switch around what I do or how I do it, mainly looking for a solution to the problem at hand. Even a workaround that doesn't involve using other browsers/debuggers.

Comment: not trolling, but actually curious: why on earth do you still use IE for everyday browsing??

Comment: Because I actually like it! Theres several reasons actually, mainly because i use a bunch of stuff that pretty much only runs in IE, for example, MS Exchange 2003 Outlook Web Access. I could use FF but i lose all the nice features of it. So I would just rather stick with a single browser...

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way I can think of would be to write a small utility to:

- Close all IE windows
- Toggle the REG_SZ registry value HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Disable Script Debugger (from "yes" to "no" or vice versa)
- Optionally restart IE

As far as I know, there's no way to make IE recognize the changed registry value without restarting it, even using an IE plugin.

As an aside, unless the IE/VS integration is critical for you, you may want to look into the combination of Firefox and [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Javascript debugging: I find it much nicer in general, and debugging can easily be enabled or disabled, either interactively or on a per-site basis.

Comment: I do use FF/Firebug also, but I still need to use IE.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using Firefox + [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419), which would allow you to easily and quickly change the rendering engine used for sites that require IE. This way the bulk of your browsing can be done in non-IE tabs and you can avoid the debug popups.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com/). It's free for personal use, and it has a 60 days trial for commercial. It works a bit like fireug for Firefox, but obviously it's going to cost to use.

Comment: thx, i will take a look at it to see how well it fits. If it alows me to still use vs as the main debugger but can be anabled and disabled, its definately something i would use. Thanks agian.